# Flutter: ShellException(dart migrate) while setting up get_cli

Tags: flutter, windows, terminal, flutter-getx, get-cli

I'm using Windows Powershell, trying to set get_cli for a Flutter project, and I'm following this tutorial https://shirsh94.medium.com/get-cli-powerful-getx-tool-for-project-management-bdf54572d91f

> Could not find a command named "migrate".
> error_unexpected ShellException(dart migrate --apply-changes
> --skip-import-check, exitCode 64, workingDirectory: path

The error occurred as the get_cli tried to run the line `dart migrate --apply-changes --skip-import-check`

Here's the result for `flutter doctor -v`:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3570], locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 3.13.8 on channel stable at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision 6c4930c4ac (3 days ago), 2023-10-18 10:57:55 -0500
> • Engine revision 767d8c75e8
> • Dart version 3.1.4
> • DevTools version 2.25.0

> [✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

> [✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
> ✗ ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\flutter\bin;
> but Android SDK not found at this location.

> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

> [✗] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
> ✗ Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
> Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
> Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

> [✓] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.83.1)
> • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.74.0

> [✓] Connected device (3 available)
> • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3570]
> • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.89
> • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 118.0.2088.57

> [✓] Network resources
> • All expected network resources are available.